# Minimize/Maximize window buttons not displayed in Gnome

Tags: java, swt, gnome

I have a `TitleAreaDialog`

```
setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.MAX | SWT.MIN);
```

I searched on web and found out that this could be caused by os:

[why maximize and minimize option is missing in linux but working in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151538/why-maximize-and-minimize-option-is-missing-in-linux-but-working-in-windows)

I have run the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

but the result was the same so it is leads me that either the set wasn't succeed or it is other problem.

For some windows the all 3 buttons are displayed but only for some only close is displayed. Can this be caused by an OS setup or it is other problem?

Comment: I think you'll be better off on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or a related page, since this isn't a question about programming, but rather about the operating system.

Comment: Posting the code might be helpful.

Comment: @dARKpRINCE The necessary code is all there. If you need a minimal running example, look at the referenced question.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. :D But anyways I can't help much since I dont have Linux System to test... :-/

Comment: I'm not sure it is only a OS related issue/configuration since for some other application it does have all 3 buttons.

Comment: @L4zy Other SWT applications?

Comment: @Baz I'm tring to develop a eclipse plugin and except the main window of eclipse which have min, max button all windows doesn't. From my understanding the OS settings apply for all application not only for swt, and all others have those buttons.

Comment: @L4zy Unfortunately I can't test it cause I'm not using gnome. Works fine on Linux Mint with cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Gnome 3.22) worked:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'

together with

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides button-layout 'appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'

Following elsewhere given answer doesn't work anymore:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout close,minimize,maximize:

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem.   Developers don't have access to users' Gnome settings in general.  The answer needs to be programmatic, not a system configuration setting.